# What's the best way to cast a variable to a boolean in php?

Tags: php, casting, boolean

I was reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891301/top-bad-practices-in-php) and saw this line:

```
if ($a == $b) { return true } else { return false }
```

And it led me to wondering, what is the best way to cast a variable of unknown type (could be string, could be int; who knows? who cares?) to a boolean?

Of course, `if ($var) { return true; } else { return false; }` would do the trick, but I think `return $var ? true : false;` is probably better.

For that matter:

- `return $var && true`
- `return $var || false`
- `return !empty($var)`

are all probably better, but is there a *best* way to cast to bool? More importantly, what makes it best?

Edit to clarify:

This wasn't written with the intention of being a comprehensive list of the ways to cast to a boolean. My question is **specifically on explicit casting**. Before I learned about `empty` I used `isset($var) && $var` as it would prevent errors from being thrown on undeclared variables. Now i use `!empty($var)` as it's faster to type.

`!empty` has the (dis)advantage of not throwing any `E_NOTICE` errors when the variable isn't defined. This could be considered good if you're checking `$_GET` or `$_SESSION` variables, for the majority of other variables, I suppose this may be considered bad as it would hide issues where a variable is uninitialized where it should have been initialized.

I was curious as to whether other developers have another way of doing things that I hadn't
known about.

Comment: I would be interested why you think that there is a best way? I for example don't think that there exists *the best code*. Of course you can find objective criteria to some extend but at one point it is becoming subjective.

Comment: @Felix Kling, it's a subjective question to be sure, I didn't want to use *best*, but I'm finding it hard to come up with good metrics to judge something as simple as boolean casting: fastest? hardly matters. shortest to type? readability?

Comment: Out of interest I [ran a quick test](https://eval.in/431853) to see which was faster and explicitly typecasting it using `(bool)` was consistently faster.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The two ways are:

1. Explicit cast:

   This is when you explicitly cast the variable using the literal cast operator `(bool)`.

   ```
   return (bool) $expression;
   ```
2. Implicit cast (using operators):

   This is where the type is inferred from the expression.  In PHP, this includes [logical operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) and [comparison operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), and any function/language construct that expects a boolean such as `if` and `while`:

   ```
   return !!$expression;
   ```

   or

   ```
   return $expression == true;
   ```

   or

   ```
   return $a == $b;
   ```

   or

   ```
   return $a > 1;
   ```

   or

   ```
   if ($a)
   ```

All methods will fall into one of those two categories.

My suggestion is that if you use any operators (`==`, `!=`, `>`, etc), don't bother casting.  But if you're just returning a variable, then cast explicitly...

Comment: shouldn't it be `return $a > 0;` rather than `return $a > 1;`?

Comment: If I saw `return !!$expression;` I could see myself deleting the double negation thinking someone made a mistake. Just keep that in mind for those who might think it's a "cool" way to type cast.

Answer (score 14):

I personally always use

```
(bool)$var;
```

I think this to be the most clear way to cast it to a boolean.  Most people coming from another language understand this.  One other one you forgot from your is

```
!!$var;
```

I find that one a little difficult to read.

Answer (score 5):

What I have seen most often in JavaScript: Double negation

```
return !!$var;
```

**Explanation:**

`!$var` evaluates `$var` to its [opposite boolean value](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) (if `$var` is no a boolean value, it is [converted to boolean first (type conversion)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)) and the second `!` inverts this value again, leading to the boolean value, `$var` would evaluate too.

Is it the best? That depends on your criteria. As already mentioned, it might be harder to understand (although it is nothing special) but it is definitely the shortest version ;)

It might also depend, which values **you** consider as `true` and `false`. These values evaluate to `false` by default:

> - the boolean FALSE itself
> - the integer 0 (zero)
> - the float 0.0 (zero)
> - the empty string, and the string "0"
> - an array with zero elements
> - an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
> - the special type NULL (including unset variables)
> - SimpleXML objects created from empty tags

**Update:**

I think in general one can say, that every code that avoids explicitly returning `true` or `false` is better. Be it through explicit casting or implicit type conversion. Of course explicit (by definition) should be easier to understand.

Having code such as `return $a ? true : false` is redundant. Especially

```
if ($a == $b) { return true } else { return false }
```

which could just be written as `return ($a == $b)`.

There must be a reason why this was frowned upon in my undergrads ;).

**Update2:**

I would avoid expression such as `return $var && true`. In PHP it would return a boolean, but e.g. in JavaScript or Python, it would return the value of `$var` if it evaluates to true. And in these languages, this "trick" is used on purpose to achieve certain effects. So for people (more) familiar with these languages, it might not be obvious (without documentation or context) that only a boolean should be returned.

Comment: How does this help with PHP? I'm just looking for more description.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: Hope that helps a bit. It works the same in PHP as in JavaScript because `!` works the same :)

Comment: @Felix - Why does this work? That's the description I was looking for.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: Mmh have you read my updated answer? Sorry, I cannot explain it better...

Comment: @Felix - I guess my point is the delicacy of understanding what is going on - that the !var is casting, and that !!var is tricky. This is not easy to track, as you state in your answer. :)

Comment: For what it's worth: double negation is useful in JavaScript because it lacks way to explicitly cast to the boolean primitive.  The only other way to cast to boolean is to use `new Boolean(value)`; however, this will fail with strict comparisons to other boolean primitives since it creates an object.  In PHP or languages that offer it, IMO you should always use a cast rather than a coercion for clarity.  There's nothing unclear about `!!$val`, but `(bool)$val` is even clearer.

Comment: @Justin Johnson: I agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

> what is the best way to cast a variable of unknown type (could be string, could be int; who knows? who cares?) to a boolean?

```
return (bool)$var;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast:

```
if ((bool)$string)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Note, in PHP since 0 == false, you need to use the === comparator to get type comparison, plus value comparison.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: What about casting to a boolean instead?

Comment: True, I didn't catch that initially, since I usually cast (int). See edit.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: In PHP, everything that isn't a boolean false or zero will evaluate as true in an if statement.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: it will be performed automatically. And iirc it is a bunch of optimizations in php core so `if($var)` will be significantly faster that `if((bool)$var)` on a millions of runs.

Comment: Oh ok, I see what you mean. Interesting question. :)

Comment: @zerkms - I'm confused at this point. Am I right/wrong/indifferent?